# Subscribing to new mail event of multiple impersonated user through one ExchangeService object

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am able to subscribe to push notifications by specifying impersonating users' credentials and then specifying impersonated user's email in `ExchangeService.ImpersonatedUserId` property.

However want to know how can I handle new email events on multiple email ids that are impersonated by one email id, since there is no collection as such on `ExchangeService` to specify multiple Impersonation Ids. In fact I think we can handle only one email id by using single `ExchangeService` object. And to subscribe to multiple user mail events, even through impersonation, I have to create multiple instances of `ExchangeService`. And also multiple callback listeners too. This is what I want confirmation about:

**Q.** Do I need to create multiple instances of `ExchangeService` and callback listeners to handle new mail event on multiple user id with impersonation?

**Q.** Without impersonation?

**Q.** Also want to know given credentials of impersonating user, can I retrieve list of all users impersonated by that user.

Comment: Fro question one, you can add multiple users to a single ExchangeService object. See this post for the code: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/01046b41-5e73-4f9a-b2fa-0344149d4f19/ews-push-notifications-subscriptions-for-multiple-mailboxes?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: hey thanks I didn't thought that, tho what about without impersonation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q.** Do I need to create multiple instances of ExchangeService and callback listeners to handle new mail event on multiple user id with impersonation?

**Ans.** In Exchange 2013 we do have the option of grouping see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_throttling) . In 2010 the only way is to use a separate Instances for every user you are impersonating.

**Q.** Without impersonation?

**Ans.** To use single user account to subscribe to events on folders of different users, user account your using for authentication must be granted Access to the Folders your subscribing to (either on the Folder using `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` or Outlook delegation) or on the Mailbox using `Add-MailboxPermission`. A single `ExchangeService` instance can have only single user account credentials associated with it.

As a side note: There are throttling limitations around the total number of subscriptions one particular user can make see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458788(v=exchg.150).aspx).

**Q.** Also want to know given credentials of impersonating user, can I retrieve list of all users impersonated by that user.

**Ans.** There is no cmdlets or EWS operations that can tell you this, however if you having logging enabled then you should be able to track the user of impersonation though the logs on IIS and the EWS.log see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2012/06/27/the-importance-of-ews-impersonation-while-using-an-application-account.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you got this answered on the Exchange Development Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4b9ed4a6-2664-4c4d-9b10-c5a03e72ae56/subscribing-to-new-mail-event-of-multiple-impersonated-user-through-one-exchangeservice-object?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment.